# What is the correct alternative to Java's equalsIgnoreCase?

Tags: java, string, localization, string-comparison

There are lots and lots of examples on why and when `java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase` will fail because of incorrect use of the locale.

But I did not find any examples of the correct way. Unlike `java.lang.String.toUpperCase` there is no version with a locale parameter. Converting both strings to upper or lower case seem to be wasteful. Especially when you are working on a application doing a lot of comparisons.

What is the correct way to make a ignore case string comparison, taking both locale and performance into consideration?

Comment: Maybe by using a [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html)?

Comment: Would you mind editing your question with examples as to wrong results of `.equalsIgnoreCase()`? I am quite curious...

Comment: @fge Turkish «i» and the German «ß» seem to be the most quoted failures. But your are right, I add some examples later.

Comment: Still waiting for examples ;)

Comment: @fge I realise that it's some time since your comment, but here's a striking example that I just came across: `"\u0130".equalsIgnoreCase("\u0130".toLowerCase())`. That code returns false (OpenJDK 1.8.0_121).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://www.globalyzer.com/gzserver/help/reference/localeSensitiveMethods/javaunsafe_cmprignrcase.html), you can use Collator to do case insensitive equality as follows:

```
//retrieve the runtime user's locale
Locale locale = new Locale(getUserLocale());

//pass the user's locale as an argument
Collator myCollator = Collator.getInstance(locale);

//set collator to Ignore case but not accents
//(default is Collator.TERTIARY, which is
//case sensitive)
myCollator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);

int i = myCollator.compare(stringA,stringB);
```

(Copied from the above site ...)

Obviously, in other contexts you might choose the locale differently.

---

For @fge - This Oracle Bug Report gives an example of the kind of thing that happens.

- http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4425387

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative might be abusing Regex. This is quite performance-intensive with dynamically changing strings, but if you are comparing against constants it *could* be an alternative:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^" + myOtherString + "$",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.LITERAL | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE).matcher();
if (matcher.matches(myString)) {
   // ...
}
```

This anchors the string you want to compare against, specifies Unicode-aware case-insensitive matching of the Literal string.

Comment: I predict that will have the same problem as using `String.equalsIgnoreCase`.  The comparison needs to be locale aware, not just Unicode aware.  (`String.equalsIgnoreCase` is also Unicode aware ... according to the `String` javadocs.)

Comment: @StephenC the cool part about this is, that the exaple given in your answer will not have the same problem. The ß -> SS problem comes from the fact that there is no uppercase equivalent to ß. only ß will match ß and ss will **not** match ß (as it happens in equalsIgnoreCase();)